# coloring in heredocs, bash

Tags: bash, colors, heredoc

If I have previously defined color variable like this:

```
txtred='\e[1;31m'
```

How would I use it in **heredoc**:

```
    cat << EOM

    [colorcode here] USAGE:

EOM
```

I mean what should I write in place of `[colorcode here]` to render that USAGE
text red? `${txtred}` won't work, as that is what I am using throughout my
bash script, outside of **heredoc**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need something to interpret the escape sequence which `cat` won't do. This is why you need `echo -e` instead of just `echo` to make it work normally.

```
cat << EOM
$(echo -e "${txtred} USAGE:")
EOM
```

works

but you could also not use escape sequences by using `textred=$(tput setaf 1)` and then just use the variable directly.

```
textred=$(tput setaf 1)

cat <<EOM
${textred}USAGE:
EOM
```

Comment: Great. Is there a way to preserve formatting, because right know as it is, it moves `USAGE` text to the right?

Comment: Sorry it does not now, when I use `${tr}` instead of `$tr`. It was because of space I needed to insert beetween `$tr` and `USAGE`.

Comment: This is a great answer! Although, I replaced `tput` with `echo` because I couldn't find a `tput` command for reset.  so `txtred=$(echo "\e[1;31m")` and `reset=$(echo "\e[0m")`. Although, if you're really into `tput` I think [this will be really helpful](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269077/tput-setaf-color-table-how-to-determine-color-codes)

Answer (score 11):

Late to the party, but another solution is to `echo -e` the entire **heredoc** block via command substitution:

```
txtred='\e[1;31m'

echo -e "$(
cat << EOM
${txtred} USAGE:
EOM
)" # this must not be on the EOM line
```

*NB: the closing `)"` must fall on a new line, or it'll break the **heredoc** end marker.*

This option might be appropriate if you have a lot of colours to use and don't want a lot of subshells to set each of them up, or you already have your escape codes defined somewhere and don't want to reinvent the wheel.